# Differences between "helm-follow-mode" and "follow-mode"

Tags: helm, follow-mode

"helm-follow-mode" vs. "follow-mode"
Basically: what is the difference between their behaviours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two different, not related things.

[(emacs) Follow Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Follow-Mode.html):

> “Follow mode” is a minor mode that makes two windows, both showing the
> same buffer, scroll as a single tall virtual window.

`C-h f helm-follow-mode`:

> Execute persistent action every time the cursor is moved.

Comment: But follow mode will persist as well for any other two windows during that session... right?

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein Not sure what does "persist" mean. `M-x follow-mode` is a buffer-local minor mode, so it's on untill you turn off the mode, though if you have just one window for the buffer, the minor is still on but should do nothing special.

Comment: so the only difference is that one will persist while the other wont.

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein These two features are not comparable. The only thing in common is their names.